# Как получить имя элемента из атрибута value у input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```html
<input class="btn" type="button" value="addClass">
<input type="text" id="qeq" name="kye" size="15" maxlength="15" value="element" />
<input type="text" id="qwq" name="kyee" size="15" maxlength="15" value="className" />
```

```js
    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var caption = $('#qeq').attr('value');
    var caption2 = $('#qwq').attr('value');
  // действия, которые будут выполнены при наступлении события...
  caption.addClass('caption2');
});
```

Есть кнопка и 2 поля ввода, хочу что бы при нажатии кнопки, элементу чьё имя введено в первом поле ввода, добавлялся класс введенный во второе поле ввода. Не работает сама функция.

Comment: Внесите получение `value` в функцию.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko внёс, но ошибка та-же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первое поле нужно точно вводить class или id или тег.
К примеру - ".btn", "#btn"

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  let el = $('#qeq').val()
  let cl = $('#qwq').val()
  $(el).addClass(cl)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='btn' class="btn" type="button" value="addClass">
<input type="text" id="qeq" name="kye" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" placeholder='элемент' />
<input type="text" id="qwq" name="kyee" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" placeholder='класс' />
```